# How to insert dates as date array in postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, date, plpgsql

I am trying to add dates into an array from a select query.

I am getting this error:

> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: malformed array literal: "2021-04-02"

```
declare dateval date[];
begin 
select days into dateval from holidays where days between '2021-01-01' and '2021-12-31' and city='NY';
```

then I need to compare this array in if statement
my date variable in this dateval array
do something or go to else like that

Answer (score 1):

You need to aggregate them into an array in order to be able to store them into one:

```
select array_agg(days) 
  into dateval
from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not need an array but use `exists` and a subquery in your `if` condition.

```sql
if my_date_var between '2021-01-01' and '2021-12-31' and exists 
(
  select from holidays 
  where my_date_var = days 
  and city='NY'
) then ...
```

or use `in` (probably less efficient)

```sql
if my_date_var in
(
  select days from holidays 
  where days between '2021-01-01' and '2021-12-31' 
  and city='NY'
) then ...
```